# How to find files which do not contain their own filename

Tags: find, grep, exit-code

When using templates to generate files, it's important to include the template's name inside the template. When reading a generated file, it helps you find the template used to generate it.

I want to search for all templates in a directory that do not contain their own filename, print the ones that I find, and exit with a non-zero code if any are found.

So far, this is what I've come up with.

```
find . -name "*.xyz" -exec sh -c 'grep -L $(basename {}) {}' \;
```

This successfully finds and prints the files, but it exits with a 0 exit code whether or not any files are found. How can I find the relevant files and exit with a non-zero code when any are found?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the relevant files and exit with a non-zero code when any are found?

Pipe the result to `grep ''`. The tool won't alter the text stream, yet it will generate exit status `0` or `1` depending on whether any line passes through it or not.

I know you want it the other way. If I were you I would accommodate to the behavior of `grep` though. My rationale is: you want to know files that meet your criteria; the command finds them, so it *succeeds* in finding if there's at least one file.

However if you insist on the opposite behavior, just [negate the exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367167). Example:

```
! find . -name "*.xyz" -exec sh -c 'grep -L "$(basename "$1")" "$1"' sh {} \; | grep ''
```

Note I have debugged your `sh` invocation inside `find`. Your original approach would backfire if `{}` expanded to `./a;rm -rf ~;.xyz` (it's a valid filename in many Linux filesystems).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like `grep .... && <do if found> || <do if not found>` does the work

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.xyz; do
    grep -q $f $f || echo "$f does not contain itself"
done
```

It will give you the list of files you're looking for, though it still returns a zero (because the echo succeeds).